# c# / renci.SshNet | executing ssh commands c# form

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ssh, telnet

I am trying to build a simple ssh tool to make things easier ( like reindexing a magento website using SSH with just a button click, but if needed I'd like to still be able to enter custom commands.

Now the problem is that once I enter a command and execute it, it only seems to give me a result of what it could do but it doesn't actually do it. 
For example : When I enter ls, it shows me a list of my folders. 
But when I enter cd dir1 (dir1 is a folder I have) it shows me no result. It doesn't direct me to the next archive either.

I'd like the results to be like how they are being shown in putty ( a terminal ), which is why I included a RichTextBox in my windows form.
[Click here to see a screenshot of my code and form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tIJL.png)

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: @Ferus7 No errors whatsoever, atleast not as far as I know.

Comment: Use 'ls' or 'dir' to get valid folders.  You can also use 'ls \' to get a listing of the root folder.

Comment: it's not about wanting to see the folders, That's working just fine @jdweng . I want to go to the next folder but it looks like it is not being executed, the reason I think that is because after I enter cd dir1, it simply shows me an empty line ( so far so good ) but when I enter a new command ( for example : ls ) it shows me the exact same result as in the beginning, as if I didn't go to the other directory.

Comment: ls will only return info if the folder contains files that you have permission to read.  So if you do a cd to a folder that is empty lt will show nothing.

Comment: the folder isn't empty though, I can do everything from within Putty with the same login creditals, it's showing me nothing becuase I only type in cd dir1 ( that's logical ) but the only thing that is not right is that once I type in ls after the previous command, it simply gives me the result of the root ( in which I was in from the start ) @jdweng

Comment: I think the carriage return may be wrong.  You may only be sending carriage return instead of carriage return and linefeed.

Comment: carriage return? what do you mean? @jdweng

Comment: Every command must have a return at the end to work.  So use '\n', '\r', or "\r\n".

Comment: @jdweng all that does is add a few empty rows, I still can't go to the next liberary for some reason

Comment: Then you do no have permission to change to the folder.  You may have permission to view folder.  I would see what folder are available.  Start with 'ls \'.  Usually there is a usr folder ('ls \usr') and then work my way down to see if I had permission to change to folder.  Your default start folder may be set wrong.

Comment: @jdweng I can acces the files and folders no problem but I can't seem to navigate, it's like my application puts me back into the root folder after every command. I do not have this problem with putty. I am trying to build a simplefied version of putty for my own use, with my own commands so that I ( for example ) can reindex with just a buttonclick I know I can do that with `php -f dir1/shell/indexer.php reindexall`. but I'd also want to be able to move through folders like I can on putty

Comment: It may be the credentials are working in putty and not in your application.  I think it time to get a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare results with app and putty.

Comment: @jdweng ssh is secured, it encrypts everything I send out and receive, how am I supposed to find it then?

Comment: I didn't realize putty (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) can use ssh encryption.  Maybe you aren't doing the encryption correctly?  Putty is open source according to article so maybe look at putty source to see what you are doing wrong.